# How to change network node colour in R

Tags: r, networking, colors

I'm trying to change the colour of the nodes dependent upon the month. At the moment, I've done it this way which isn't concise at all and wouldn't work for large datasets. Is there a better way of doing it?

```
Data <- read.csv(.....) 
libary(igraph)   
MartixData <- as.matrix(Data)
NetworkData <- graph.adjacency(MatrixData, mode="directed", weighted=TRUE)
V(NetworkData)
V(NetworkData)$month <- c("June", "July", "July", "February", "September", "June", "September", "June", "December", "September", "March", "April", "September")
plot(NetworkData, layout=layout.circle, vertex.color=c("yellow", "red", "red", "blue", "pink","yellow", "pink", "yellow", "gray", "pink", "black", "orange", "pink"))
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
#Results for dput(Data)
    structure(list(13, TRUE, c(0, 1, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
10, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12), c(11, 4, 12, 0, 12, 1, 6, 12, 1, 4, 9, 12, 1, 5, 7, 10, 11), c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16), c(3, 5, 8, 12, 1, 9, 13, 6, 14, 10, 15, 0, 16, 2, 4, 7, 11), c(0, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 12, 17), c(0, 1, 4, 4, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10, 11, 13, 17), list(c(1, 0, 1), structure(list(), .Names = character(0)), 
 structure(list(name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", 
    "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M"), month = c("June", 
    "July", "July", "February", "September", "June", "September", 
    "June", "December", "September", "March", "April", "September"
    )), .Names = c("name", "month")), structure(list(weight = c(6, 
    6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7)), .Names = "weight")), 
<environment>), class = "igraph")
```

Comment: Could you please tell us what `V()` is supposed to be, e. g. fro, which package? Please state it with `library(<package>)` at the beginning of your code.

Comment: In addition,  please provide `Data` using `dput(Data)` and paste the result into your question.

Comment: I've added the comments above to my original question :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the colour of nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47463271/how-to-change-the-colour-of-nodes)